# macport and FINK

Tags: python, macos, port, fink

I have a mac server and I have both FINK and macport installation of python/numpy/scipy

I was wondering if having both will affect the other? In terms of memory leaks/unusual results? 
In case you are wondering why both ? Well I like FINK but macports allows me to have python2.4 which FINK does not provide (yes I needed an old version for a piece of code I have)

I wonder this since I tried to use homebrew once and it complained about the machine having port and FINK (I did not realize that port provided python2.4 so was looking at homebrew but when I realized port did give 2.4 I abandoned it)

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd recommend going with Homebrew instead; `fink` feels like abandonware and Homebrew is now widely preferred over MacPorts for various reasons.

Comment: Is there a reason Erik that homwbrew is better than FINK/PORT?

Comment: That's a perfectly good question to ask from Google :)

Comment: Basically it's about momentum above all—Homebrew now seems to be the first preference of the OS X community, and that itself is a reason to migrate; however, as to the specific reasons why the preference has changed, just google.

Comment: well I did ask and as everything people seem to have their "favorites" but I will look into it more.  The only reason I am reluctant to switch is that some of the stuff I have already works in PORT/FINK and homebrew does not install with PORT/FINK present which I am reluctant to remove-thank you for your answer.

Comment: You can easily move MacPorts and Fink aside for 5 minutes; install Homebrew, and see how it works out; if there's something missing, you uninstall Homebrew (and move it aside) and move MacPorts and Fink back to their installation paths.

Comment: sorry this might sound dumb but I am not an IT person but "aside"? You mean do the following?                                                    sudo port -fp uninstall installed

Comment: no, `sudo mv /opt/local /opt/local.bak` or smth; literally "move aside".

Answer (score 0):

In terms of how your Python interpreter works, no: there is no negative effect on having Fink Python as well as MacPorts Python installed on the same machine, just as there is no effect from having multiple installations of Python by anything.